# Alternatives to pylint-protobuf

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, protobuf-python

I use `pylint` with the plugin `pylint-protobuf` to typecheck the proto code. However, `pylint` does not support `protobuf >= 3.20`. ([Source](https://github.com/nelfin/pylint-protobuf/issues/54)) Going back to an older version of protobuf is not an option.

Are there alternative plug-ins to `pylint-protobuf` or alternatives to `pylint` that provide at least some basic support to `protobuf` type checking (some form of equivalency to pylint-protobuf` or better)

Note: this is with Python 3.11, Protobug 4.24.0rc2